# Segmentation Fault while reading multiple lines from a text file character-by-character

Tags: c, realloc

I am trying to read lines from a file, one character at a time.

Input example:

```
5 2
2
1 3
2 4 5
3
```

Suppose I am trying to read the first line, then I am reading '5' first, then the space (' ') and then the '2', and then trying to store the two number in a array, which I am declarig using `realloc` because I don't know how many numbers will be there in a line before reading the line.
I only knwo the number of lines that will be present in the file `numNodes`.

I am trying to store the numbers in a 2D array, where each row will have differnet lengths.
Since I don't know th length of each line beforehand, I am allocating memory using `realloc` after reading each number.

Since the numbers can be more than one-digited, i am storing the characters in `num` character array and when i encounter a space(' ') or newline('\n'), I convert it to a number using `atoi`, and store it in the suitable row, after allocating memory to it using `realloc`.

here's my code

```
FILE *fp;

fp = fopen("input.txt","r");

char ch;
int numNodes = 5, i = 0;

int **adjList = (int **)malloc(numNodes*sizeof(int *));

int len = 0,j,k=0;
char num[4];

for(i=0;i<numNodes;i++)
{
    adjList[i] = NULL;
    printf("Node %d -> ",i+1);
    do
    {
        //read = 
        fscanf(fp,"%c",&ch);
        if(ch!=' ' && ch!='\n')
        {
            num[k]=ch;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            k = 0;
            len++;
            adjList[i] = (int *)realloc(adjList[i],sizeof(int)*len);
            adjList[i][len-1] = atoi(num);
            for(k=0;k<4;k++)
                num[k]='0';
        }

    }
    while(ch!='\n');

    for(j=0;j<len;j++)
        printf("%d ",adjList[i][j]);
    printf("\n");

    len = 0;
}
```

However, I am getting `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)` on the last line, that is, after `2 4 5` gets printed.

Any help is appreciated, as to, why this error is occuring on the last line?

**EDIT** :

1. Changed `ch` to `&ch` in `fscanf` line
2. Changed `ch[0]` to `ch`(`if` statement)
3. Added `adjlist[i] = NULL` before `do...while` loop

Comment: `fscanf(fp,"%c",ch);` what is type of `ch`? If it is `char` you should be using `&ch` or if it is `char *` you should be using `%s` format specifier.

Comment: @kiranBiradar I declared it like `char ch[1]`.

Comment: The first argument to `realloc` needs to be a value returned by a previous `malloc/relloc` or `NULL`. The first time `realloc(adjList[i]` is called the `adjList[i]` value is undefined as the elements of `adjList` were never initialised.

Comment: @Siladittya Initialize `adjList[i] = NULL;` before starting `do...while` loop.

Comment: @kaylum 
@kiranBiradar
I wrote this line `adjList[i] = NULL;` just after the `for` loop line and ran the code again. But still getting the same error.

Comment: Also @kiranBiradar made the change you said to do, I will change the code in the question accordingly.

Comment: Then suggest you run the program in a debugger and/or add more debug print statements. At a minimum you should check the value of all the variables when the crash happens to see if any are unexpected.

Comment: Also  a requirement of Stack Overflow debug requests is to provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without that it makes it much harder for people to help as we can't easily run the program ourselves. Your code is already very close to a MVE. Just need to provide a value for `numNodes` and a few missing variable declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    fscanf(fp,"%c",&ch);
    if(ch!=' ' && ch!='\n')
    {
        num[k]=ch;
        k++;
    }
    else
    {
        k = 0;
        len++;
        adjList[i] = (int *)realloc(adjList[i],sizeof(int)*len);
        adjList[i][len-1] = atoi(num);
        for(k=0;k<4;k++)
            num[k]='0';
    }
```

When you finish reading one number `k` will be `4`.

```
    for(k=0;k<4;k++)
        num[k]='0';
```

And you start reading the next number with `k >= 4` thus access out of bound for `num` .

```
        num[k]=ch;
        k++;
```

---

Also you need to terminate the `num` with `\0` char to be used with `atoi`.

```
num[k] = '\0';
adjList[i][len-1] = atoi(num);
```

Comment: If that is so, then there is also a single number in the second line, then the error should have occurred in the second line itself. Isn't it?

Comment: Welcome to world of undefined behavior.

Comment: I used `k=0` after the `for` loop, the problem still persists. If I convert the `do...while` loop to `while` loop I get a `*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated` error.

Comment: After using `k=0` after the for loop `for(k=0;k<4;k++)` I am getting 1000 and 3000 instead of 1 and 3 in the third line. But 1 and 3 if I do not use it. And still getting Segmentation Fault.

Comment: Okay. My bad.

However, added a line `read = fscanf(fp,"%c",&ch);
   if(read==EOF)
    break;` and it is now working. Thanks for pointing out the mistakes.

Comment: You need to terminate the `num` array with `\0` before using it with `atoi`.